# Is there a way to predict change based on data?

Tags: predictive-models, modeling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to predict future change based on data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25181/is-there-a-way-to-predict-future-change-based-on-data)

I do not know anything about statistics. I am a software engineer.

I had a question in my mind and I think here is the place to get my answer.

Suppose that I have data for 3 months. The data shows my visitors on a daily basis. Is there a possible way to know how many visitors I will have in e.g. 6 months? If yes, I guess there are some factors to be considered. What are they?

Also, the number of visitors in the 180 day will be predicted only approximately and must have some risk on it. How can the risk be defined?

Any links or info about this are very welcome. Thank you community.

Comment: Exact duplicate, same asker :P

Comment: Please, don't cross post in the future.